# Get list of all combinations from a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, reinventing-the-wheel

Given a tuple of elements, in `elementTupleParam` and the number in each combination `r`, we compute all the possible combinations of `r` elements, in a list of tuples. This is a recursive implementation.

One "challenge" is the inputs `r`, `n`, `elementTuple`, and the list holding the results, `combinationList`, are shared for all invocations of the recursive function. One method is to use global variables and bind them like below; which I think is rather ugly/bloated. Another method is to pass these are parameters to the recursive function, which may result in long parameter lists. Yet another is to make `partialCombinations` an inner function of `getCombinations`.

Another issue is the choice of data structure to hold the partial combinations and the result. I chose `tuple` because it's immutable: `prevTuple` is shared across many subsequent invocations, and is less prone to errors caused by accidental modifications.

What do you think? Any thoughts on these or other aspects would be appreciated.

```
r = 0
n = 0
elementTuple = ()
combinationList = []

# get the vanilla combinations, nCr in number
def getCombinations(elementTupleParam, rParam):
    global r
    global n
    global elementTuple
    global combinationList

    r = rParam
    elementTuple = tuple(elementTupleParam)
    n = len(elementTuple)
    combinationList = []

    if r == 0 or n == 0 or r > n:
        return combinationList

    partialCombinations((), -1)

    return combinationList

def partialCombinations(prevTuple, prevVisitedIndex):
    for thisIndex in range(prevVisitedIndex + 1, n):
        thisTuple = prevTuple + (elementTuple[thisIndex],)

        # If we exhausted all indices and have not formed a long enough tuple, then this is a dead-end, and don't do anything
        if thisIndex == n - 1 and not len(thisTuple) == r:
            continue

        if len(thisTuple) == r: # Found combination
            combinationList.append(thisTuple)
            continue

        partialCombinations(thisTuple, thisIndex)

#sanity check, should be moved to a unit test in another file
if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = getCombinations((2,3,4), 2)
    print(result)
```

Comment: In those combinations, is order important?

Comment: @Gloweye No, it's not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Style

I suggest you check PEP0008 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ the official Python style guide while writing your code and the following goes accordingly:

- **Docstrings:** Python Docstring is the documentation string which is string literal, and it occurs in the class, module, function or method definition, and it is written as a first statement. Docstrings are accessible from the doc attribute for any of the Python object and also with the built-in help() function can come in handy. I suggest you include docstrings to your functions indicating what they do and what they return instead of writing a comment above each function.
- **Python naming conventions:**

  `def getCombinations(elementTupleParam, rParam):`

  `def partialCombinations(prevTuple, prevVisitedIndex):`

  Function names should be lowercase, with words separated
  by underscores as necessary to improve readability same goes for
  parameter names.
- **Descriptive variable names:** `thisIndex` `thisTuple` `prevTuple` are examples of bad non-descriptive names. Names should reflect the significance of the variable/function/parameter they represent and the less ambiguous they are, the more readable is your code.

## Code

- **Global variables:** are bad in Python and programming languages in general and are advised against. I suggest enclosing variables inside functions. The reason they are bad that they may allow functions to have hidden/hard to detect side effects leading to an increased complexity potentially leading to Spaghetti code. Examples of good use of global variables include: algorithm optimization - caching and memoization.
- There is a built-in Python library `itertools` that does the same functionality using `itertools.combinations()` which saves you the effort of implementing the thing yourself.

  **Code can be shortened into the following:**
  And according to GZO's comment, there is no need for the warpper function `get_combinations()`, use `combinations()` directly. I included it just for the sake of the example.

  ```
  from itertools import combinations


  def get_combinations(n: list, r: int):
      """Return combinations iterator."""
      return combinations(n, r)


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      print(list(get_combinations([2, 3, 4], 2)))
  ```

**Check these references(regarding global variables):**

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil

Comment: Good call on using type hints for function parameters (even though they're just comments in Python).

Comment: Thanks man, I hope i was of some help.

Comment: There is no need for the wrapper function `get_combinations` function when `combinations` is used.

Comment: @GZO I know, it's just for the sake of the example.

Comment: *main guard: shouldn't be moved to another file* - This is not true. It's beneficial in a module for functions to be separated into separate files as logic and organization dictate. Often, a module's `__main__.py` will have little code other than an entry point.

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks for letting me know, I'll remove that part

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @bullseye, the `itertools` library provides `combinations()`.

If you are trying to learn how to implement your own version, here is a simple recursive version:

```
def combinations(seq, r):
    """returns a list of all r-length combinations of the elements of seq."""

    if len(seq) == r:
        # only one combination
        return [seq]

    elif r == 0:
        # yield an empty seq of the same type as seq
        return [seq[:0]]

    else:
               # combinations that _include_ seq[0]                    + those that exclude seq[0]
        return [seq[:1] + tail for tail in combinations(seq[1:], r-1)] + combinations(seq[1:], r)
```

Example:

```
combinations((1,2,3,4), 3), combinations('abcde', 3)
```

Output:

```
([(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)],
 ['abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'acd', 'ace', 'ade', 'bcd', 'bce', 'bde', 'cde'])
```

Here is an alternative version that generates the combinations lazily:

```
def combinations(seq, r):
    if len(seq) == r:
        # only one combination
        yield seq

    elif r == 0:
        # yield an empty seq of the same type as seq
        yield seq[:0]

    else:
        # yield all combinations that _include_ seq[0]
        yield from (seq[:1] + tail for tail in combinations(seq[1:], r-1))

        # yield all combinations that _exclude_ seq[0]
        yield from combinations(seq[1:], r)
```